# How many type of "extension" hybris have?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new in **hybris** please tell me anyone how many type of **"extension"** hybris have?

Answer (score 1):

Hybris Commerce comes with the following extensions, which you can use as a template for new extensions:

1. yempty
2. ycockpit
3. yaddon
4. ybackoffice
5. yacceleratorcore
6. yacceleratorfacades
7. yacceleratorstorefront
8. yacceleratorcockpits
9. yacceleratorinitialdata
10. yacceleratortest
11. ycommercewebservices
12. yacceleratorordermanagement
13. yacceleratorfulflmentprocess
14. yatddtests
15. ycommercewebserviceshmc
16. ycommercewebservicestest
17. ygroovy
18. yoccaddon
19. ysaporderfulfillment
20. ysapordermgmtb2baddon
21. ysapproductconfigb2baddon
22. yscala
23. yhacext

Comment: Those are not type of extensions but available templates, types are core, web, hmc, addons, backoffice, part of module gen. (extensions can be of more than one type)

Comment: In addition to the list of extensions mentioned by @BenoitVanalderweireldt, facades, initialdata, fulfilmentprocess and many more. Just execute module gen and you will get 7 or more important extensions created initially.

Answer (score 1):

All hybris extensions have the same minimal structure :

```
/.externalToolBuilders directory
/.settings directory
/lib directory
/resources directory
/src directory
/testsrc directory
/web directory
.classpath file
.pmd file
.project file
.ruleset file
.springBeans file
buildcallbacks.xml
extensioninfo.xml file
project.properties file
external-dependencies.xml file
```

So there is only one type of extension.

You can then make some different "group" of extension :

- your custom extensions in /custom
- the extensions working in module, that have always, a core, a hmc and a web extension
- the platform extensions in /platform
- the business extensions in /bin
- the template extensions, starting with 'y' anf containing an `extgen.propertiesfile. You can have the up to date list of template [there](https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8b96270b86691014b1c3bbfd7556f0ed.html)

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are two different types of extensions in Hybris:

1. Web extensions (webmodule) which expose an access url : yacceleratorstorefront, hmc, ...
2. Core extensions (coremodule) which basically contains logics : platform, yacceleratorcore, yacceleratorfacades,...

Note: And also some extensions can be both web and core at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSA28.png)

According to your answer

- Core Extensions - Used for platform implementation
- Web Extensions  - Used for Storefront applications - Like facades,addons, etc.
- Commerce Extensions - Like payment, fulfillments, etc.

Other usual types are stated  below according to hybris commerce suite

Answer (score 0):

I would say that depends on your config...

according to the previous comments you got you may also have a look at the documentation by SAP https://help.hybris.com

There is a complete capture about Getting started, Creating new Extensions with the core trail and so on. It may help you as well to understand which extensions are possible in which configuration-set according to the accelerator you've chosen and stuff :)